# What extra does packer do apart from building a machine image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, google-cloud-platform, operating-system, packer

On [packer's website](https://www.packer.io/), it says "Create identical machine images for multiple platforms from a single source configuration."

After a machine image has been created, what extra needs to be done, so that it can run different platforms (such as GCP and AWS)? Suppose I create a machine image using docker/podman, wouldn't that machine image run on a GCP or AWS machine by default? Is packer doing something extra so as to make sure that these machine images will work on different platforms?

Comment: Packer lets you define a complete system configuration; so not the software packaged in Docker, but the Docker daemon, sshd, monitoring tools, and other things on the host it runs on.  You can commit the `*.pkr.hcl` files to source control and Packer has pluggable backends to directly create things like Amazon Machine Images (AMIs).  This isn't really a programming question _per se_ and another site like [devops.se] might be a better place to ask about this class of tool.

Comment: You cannot really mix `sources` like this unless the plugin has something (e.g. vagrant post-processor) to convert the output artifact into a format usable by another platform.